# Как правильно орагнизовать линковку release и debug версий библиотеки?

Tags: visual-studio, библиотеки, cmake

Использую для своего проекта `protobuf.lib`. Собираю ее в режиме релиза, добавляю получившиеся файлы (`*.lib`) в свой проект, линкую в `смаке`, собираю свой проект в режиме релиза - все работает хорошо.

Но обычно то проект я собираю в режиме дебага. Теперь чтоб подключить либу я собираю ее в режиме дебага, получаю файлы `*d.lib` .... и что дальше? Если я просто релизные файлы заменю `*d.dll` То сборка моего проекта в режиме отладки вызовет ошибку что не находит файлов `*.lib`.

Вопрос: как правильно организовать (в разные ли папки складывать?) и подключить, чтоб автоматически подключались нужные библиотеки?

**UPD:**

Прилагаю смаке

```
project(protobuff)
file(GLOB PROTO_FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.proto")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

link_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuff-lib/")

set (PROTOBUF_LIBRARY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuff-lib/libprotobuf.lib")
set (PROTOBUF_PROTOC_LIBRARY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuff-lib/libprotoc")
set (PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuff-lib/protoc")

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuff-lib/include")
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${PROTO_FILES})

set(SRC_LIST
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(protobuff
    ${SRC_LIST}
    ${PROTO_SRCS} 
    ${PROTO_HDRS}
)

target_link_libraries(protobuff ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я Вам уже говорил, делаете:

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(... ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

И больше ни о чём не беспокоитесь.

---

Ну если Вы самостоятельно начали выставлять `PROTOBUF_LIBRARY`, `PROTOBUF_PROTOC_LIBRARY` и т.д. тогда идите дальше и выставляйте `PROTOBUF_LIBRARY_DEBUG` и т.д. По уму же, насколько я понимаю, для нахождения этой библиотеки можно использовать:

```
# ``PROTOBUF_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER``
#   When compiling with MSVC, if this cache variable is set
#   the protobuf-default VS project build locations
#   (vsprojects/Debug & vsprojects/Release) will be searched
#   for libraries and binaries.
# ``PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS``
#   List of additional directories to be searched for
#   imported .proto files.
```

А всё остальное должно быть найдёно и выставлено скриптом. Кстати, Вы можете посмотреть, что содержится в `${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}` выведя значение этой переменной в `message`:

```
message(${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

Таким образом Вы сможете понять, что не так у Вас происходит.

Comment: Делаю именно так, по ссылке которую вы давали есть пример - им воспользовалась, но пути все равно просит - добавила в вопрос код смаке. Файлы то библиотеки я сама собираю и получаю разные, куда их все складывать?

Comment: @Mira, обновил ответ

Comment: По поводу переменных дебага - сейчас попробую, а по поводу ручного выставления - как - самостоятельно не выставлять - если просит?
1>  -- Could NOT find PROTOBUF (missing:  PROTOBUF_LIBRARY PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR)
1>  -- Could NOT find PROTOBUF (missing:  PROTOBUF_LIBRARY PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR)
1>CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
1>  Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
1>  PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED) и т д

Comment: @Mira, в CMake у скриптов, обычно, есть переменные, которые помогают найти package. Их и нужно использовать, в этой библиотеке это, похоже, `PROTOBUF_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER` вот ей и надо пользоваться

Comment: Выставила debug переменные, файлы сложила в одну папку - все сработало. Спасибо за ответ )